# How put Image in one colunm and an Table in another?

Tags: two-column

I tried to use this, but my table doesn't appears:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{imagens/image.png} 

\columnbreak

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Faixa de consumo $(m^3)$  & Valor (R\$)\\
\hline
Até 10 & 15,10\\
 & (valor fixo)\\
\hline 
De 11 a 20 & Acrescentar\\
 & 2,35 por $m^3$\\
 \hline 
 De 21 a 50 & Acrescentar\\
  & 5,50 por $m^3$\\
  \hline 
  Acima de 50 & Acrescentar \\
  & 6,10 por $m^3$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: I would recommend looking through https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/107497.  `{table}` means that it can float to where TeX thinks is best, which isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you like to have image and table in parallel like this:

[image]

For this is `multicols` wrong environment since it not allow to contain floats. SO just dropped out and write something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-duck}%{imagens/image.png}
%
\hfil
%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
Faixa de consumo $(m^3)$  & Valor (R\$)\\
    \hline
Até 10      & 15,10\\
            & (valor fixo)\\
    \hline
De 11 a 20  & Acrescentar\\
            & 2,35 por $m^3$\\
 \hline
De 21 a 50  & Acrescentar\\
            & 5,50 por $m^3$\\
  \hline
Acima de 50 & Acrescentar \\
  & 6,10 por $m^3$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  This is one of the more convenient approached.  At least, it would have been if the tabular had fit without adjusting the column widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\globalcounter{figure}
\globalcounter{table}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Faixa de consumo $(m^3)$  & Valor (R\$)\\
\hline
Até 10 & 15,10\\
 & (valor fixo)\\
\hline 
De 11 a 20 & Acrescentar\\
 & 2,35 por $m^3$\\
 \hline 
 De 21 a 50 & Acrescentar\\
  & 5,50 por $m^3$\\
  \hline 
  Acima de 50 & Acrescentar \\
  & 6,10 por $m^3$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}% measure width of tabular
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}% right column use remaining space
\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}

\switchcolumn

\begin{table}
\caption{Example table}
\centering% not actually needed
\usebox\tempbox
\end{table}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```